# CSS Selectors - Selecting a specific child element

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is my code snippet:

```
<div class="totals">
        <table id="shopping-cart-totals-table">
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
    <td style="" class="a-right" colspan="1">

        <strong>Grand Total</strong>
    </td>
    <td style="" class="a-right">
        <strong><span class="price">$364.99</span></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
    <td style="" class="a-right" colspan="1">
        Subtotal    </td>
    <td style="" class="a-right">
        <span class="price">$354.99</span>    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="" class="a-right" colspan="1">

        Shipping & Handling (Flat Rate - Fixed)    </td>
    <td style="" class="a-right">
        <span class="price">$10.00</span>    </td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way to select the span displaying "$10.00"?  Perhaps selecting the 2nd occurrence of an element?  I.E.: The second time ".totals table tbody tr td[colspan='']" occurs?

Comment: Please remember to encode your `&` characters (`&amp;`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With CSS3's `:nth-child()` it's easy to fulfill the "specific" criterion:

```
#shopping-cart-totals-table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) .price
```

Or, an alternative that works more in favor of browser compatibility (does not use CSS3 selectors, assumes exactly two `tr`s and two `td`s):

```
#shopping-cart-totals-table > tbody > tr + tr > td + td .price
```

Comment: Don't you need to add `span` to the end of that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to change the output of the shopping cart,  you could add a class to the `<tr>` tag,  e.g. `<tr class="row01">`, `<tr class="row02">`, etc.

If you can't change your back-end,  then it's a choice of front-end tech.  The most cross-browser method is to use jQuery to apply the row classes.  The other alternative,  CSS3,  isn't supported by any current IE;  given that this is a shopping cart,  you're probably interested in the widest level of browser support.

Something like:

```
$('#shopping-cart-totals-table tr').each(function(n){
    $(this).addClass('row'+n);
});
```

Alternatively,  if you're only interested in the third item,  use jQuery in the same way as CSS3:

```
$('#shopping-cart-totals-table tr:nth-child(2) .price').addClass('highlightClass');
```